# how to set image on cell through togglebutton in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

Hi I try this code but it not show image on cell  where i am wrong i want when i click every cell then i want to display image or when i scroll cell then image not disappear it should be appear on that cell i use this code but it not working pease help me on this.

---

```
@interface imageclass : UITableViewController
{

    BOOL changeimagetype;
    //UIImage *btnImage;
    UIButton *mimageButton;
    UIImageView *onButtonView;

}

@property (nonatomic,retain)UIImageView *onButtonView;
@property BOOL changeimagetype;
@property (nonatomic,retain)UIButton *mimageButton;

-(void)changeMapType:(id)sender;
@end
```

---

```
#import "imageclass.h"


@implementation imageclass
@synthesize onButtonView,changeimagetype,mimageButton;



-(void)changeMapType:(id)sender
{
    changeimagetype =!changeimagetype;
    if(changeimagetype == YES)
    {
        //[typechange setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        //self.myGreatMapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
        onButtonView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_OF.png"];
        [mimageButton setImage:onButtonView.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        //someBarButtonItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_ON..png"];
        //changeimagetype =NO;
    }
    else
    {
        //self.myGreatMapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;     
        onButtonView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_ON.png"];
        [mimageButton setImage:onButtonView.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }


    mimageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    mimageButton.frame=CGRectMake(10, 10, 30, 50);
    mimageButton.tag = 1;               

    onButtonView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 50)];
    onButtonView.tag = 2;
    onButtonView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_ON.png"];
    [mimageButton setBackgroundImage:[onButtonView.image stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:mimageButton];
    [mimageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeMapType:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [onButtonView release];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

---

Comment: what exactly you want to do can you explain in detail.

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper i want to dispaly image on cell by default the on.png is show on button when i click that button which is on cell then image should change off.png but it not work proper .if i scroll tableview cell then my image is disappear it not stable that place how to solve it help me on this topic

Comment: you setting background image of button in tableview delegate and setting button image changeMapType action. what are you trying to do?

Comment: you need to save that value of your toggle button in a BOOL variable as whenever your tableview reloads your button gets initialized again and the image gets changed

Comment: Dude.. you are using tableview. Plz do reload tableview after the changes.

Comment: @AnilKumarReddy can u explain me how to do it i try lot but it not working can u help me on this

Comment: If you are just using delegate methods there is no need to handle anything. But if any of the properties are getting modified outside the delegate methods, you need to reload the tableview.  [self.tableView reloadData]; do it in your changemaptype method

Comment: @AnilKumarReddy it not working i want my button work on every cell but it not work on every cell it work only last cell of tableview

Answer (score 1):

Define you tableview delegate like this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    mimageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    mimageButton.frame=CGRectMake(10, 10, 30, 50);
    mimageButton.tag = 1;               

    onButtonView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 50)];
    onButtonView.tag = 2;
    onButtonView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_ON.png"];
    [mimageButton setBackgroundImage:[onButtonView.image stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:mimageButton];
    [mimageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeMapType:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [onButtonView release];
    }
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this different approach, and it worked.
While configuring the button,

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
mimageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
mimageButton.frame=CGRectMake(10, 10, 30, 50);
mimageButton.tag = 1;               
[tempButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_ON.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[tempButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_OF.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[cell.contentView addSubview:mimageButton];
[mimageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeMapType:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
// Configure the cell...

return cell;
```

}

And in changeMapType: method,

```
-(void)changeMapType:(id)sender{
    changeimagetype =!changeimagetype;
    sender.selected = changeimagetype;
 }
```

Comment: can u give some sample on this how to do this

Comment: This is the sample code. in cellForRowAtIndexPath, after you have created the mimageButton, after the line  "mimageButton.tag = 1;", replace the next4 lines with the first three lines in my answer. And replace your changeMapType: method with the one i have provided.

Comment: in this method i get error -(void)changeMapType:(id)sender{
    changeimagetype =!changeimagetype;
    sender.selected = changeimagetype;//here i get error /Users/pradeepyadav/Desktop/tableimage/Classes/imageclass.m:59:0 /Users/pradeepyadav/Desktop/tableimage/Classes/imageclass.m:59: error: request for member 'selected' in something not a structure or union



 }

Comment: change the method signature to, -(void)changeMapTyoe:(UIButton *)sender. Or typecast sender to a pointer of UIButton

Comment: shanti kamichetty i try as par ur code but now my image is not display on cell how it work please help me my cell show me blank

Comment: I have edited my answer and have included the entire cellForRowAtIndexpath method. Can you check if you have missed out anything

Comment: shanti kamichetty it work on simple tableviewcell but in my custom tableviewcell it not working proper how handle in custom cell

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5396/discussion-between-shanti-kamichetty-and-rocky)

Comment: hi can u come on chat shanti kamichetty

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:-
Add this in cellForRowAtIndexPath method. And also set flag variable in your target method for togglebutton.

```
 if(flagButton)
{
    onButtonView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_ON.png"];
}
else
{
     onButtonView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_OFF.png"];
}
```

Comment: i want to change image on click i am create button in cell not in view how it work please explain me

Comment: the code that you written for on target of button is correct just you need to set flagButton YES or NO  in your method changeMapType: plus you need to add above code in your cellforindexpath